# How can i clear foreign cookies in my phonegap app?

Tags: cookies, webview, cordova, inappbrowser

i have a phonegap application, in which i use inAppBrowser to open other sites. And i need to clean cookies after user logout or after closing inAppBrowser. But inAppBrowser hasn't such method. Can someone help me to solve my problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you're asking for code then you're going to have to post some code first.

Comment: I checked the documentation about phonegap, but didn't find any solutions. Then i start to looking for any plugins which can help me to solve this problem, but didn't find it.
it would awesome if i could clean all my cookies, by running "magic script".

Answer (score 2):

You can clear InAppBrowser cookies using the "clearsessioncache" attribute:

```
window.open("some.url.com", "_blank", "location=no,clearsessioncache=yes");
```

However, it appears that this flag is only available [on Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser). That might be a deficiency in PhoneGap, or perhaps only Android preserves InAppBrowser cookies; I'm not sure on that point.